# Meta.meta.Math.SE: Synonomize [answer] and [answers]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, tag-management

Here on Meta, we have the tags [answer](/questions/tagged/answer) and [answers](/questions/tagged/answers).  I suggest that they be synonymized, as they refer to the same basic idea.  I don't have 5 rep in either tag, so I can't suggest it myself.

Aside: If there is an overall thread for tag synonyms on meta, please point me to it...

Comment: The thread is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1363/43351).

Comment: I don't recall seeing discussion about meta-tags there, @Lord_Farin (Of course that does not mean that that thread cannot be used for such suggestions; but I would be somewhat hesitant to post it there.)

Comment: @anorton If you want to produce link to a tag used on meta, the syntax is `[meta-tag:answer]`. If you use `[tag:answer]`, the link will point to the main site. Compare ([meta-tag:answer]) and ([tag:answer]). For more, see editing help on [comment formatting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) and on [tags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tags).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$